# How to track error for compile error in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, compilation, compiler-errors

I have maven java project that is compiled fine in command line, but when I import in eclipse I receive compilation errors about CollectionUtils.

```
org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils
```

Seems that project has transitive dependencies that has reference to old versions of apache commons collections.
How to track exactly error?
How to fix?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could track down the transitive dependencies by issuing `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out which dependency in your pom is pulling in the older version of Apache commons.

Alternatively, inside eclipse when you open the pom.xml file (with the **[m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/)** plugin installed) you should see the *Dependency Tree* tab at the bottom of the Editor like so :

[image]

In the **Search** field you could type the name of the apache commons jar to find out which dependency is pulling it in. Once you have that add the appropriate *exclusion* add it should all be peachy.

**Question**

How did you import the maven project inside eclipse. Did you do a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and then import it as a normal eclipse project ? If so, I would recommend installing the m2e plugin (linked above) and then importing the maven project using `Import Existing Maven Project` from within eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the classpath (`.classpath` file) in Eclipse is not correctly configured. You can have maven configure this for you by using the [Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/). Simply execute the following from the command line:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Maven will then correctly fill the `.classpath` file with all dependencies (including transitive dependencies) defined in your POM. Then refresh the project in Eclipse and all of the red crosses should disappear (hopefully...)

Comment: Also make sure you are using the same version of Maven in eclipse that you are from the command line.  Maven 2 and Maven 3 resolve dependencies differently.

Answer (score 0):

> How to track exactly error? How to fix?

invoke

```
mvn clean compile -e
```

it will give you error stacktrace that would help you to fix this error

Comment: the problem that project from command line or my eclipse maven plugin compiled fine=without errors. But eclipse compiler produces errors!